# Why does UIPageViewController's transition change the font?

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, ios8, uipageviewcontroller

I have an app that uses a UIPageViewController to present a quick guide on first launch.
The UI is built in a storyboard - each page has the same nib and VC, but the text changes.
The UILabels have a custom font (GothamRounded-Book) set in the Storyboard, which shows correctly in previews.
However, they always display as the system font when running on a device.

After some investigation, I added an observer to the lable's font property, and it is changed at first appearance and whenever the page changes (Horizontal Scroll). Logging and stack traces below.

Why? How can I stop it?

```
viewDidLoad: <UICTFont: 0x14783630> font-family: \"GothamRounded-Book\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt

viewDidAppear: <UICTFont: 0x14783630> font-family: \"GothamRounded-Book\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt

change: {
    kind = 1;
    new = "<UICTFont: 0x1478ab40> font-family: \".HelveticaNeueInterface-Regular\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt";
    old = "<UICTFont: 0x14783630> font-family: \"GothamRounded-Book\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt";
}

frame #1: 0x2b2d8eba Foundation`NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 262
...
frame #6: 0x2b2f834e Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 310
frame #7: 0x2e053d20 UIKit`-[_UIAttributeTraitStorage applyRecordsMatchingTraitCollection:] + 296
frame #8: 0x2e053518 UIKit`-[NSObject(_UITraitStorageAccessors) _applyTraitStorageRecordsForTraitCollection:] + 164
frame #9: 0x2df6ade2 UIKit`-[UIView _traitCollectionDidChangeFromOldCollection:toNewCollection:scaleDidChange:] + 58
frame #10: 0x2df6aea0 UIKit`-[UIView _wrappedProcessDidChangeRecursivelyFromOldTraits:toCurrentTraits:scaleDidChange:forceNotification:] + 128
frame #11: 0x2df6b0a0 UIKit`__86-[UIView _processDidChangeRecursivelyFromOldTraits:toCurrentTraits:forceNotification:]_block_invoke + 44
frame #12: 0x2e2fe830 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withUnsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspendedIfEngineDelegateExists:] + 120
frame #13: 0x2df6b068 UIKit`-[UIView _processDidChangeRecursivelyFromOldTraits:toCurrentTraits:forceNotification:] + 252
frame #14: 0x2dccafae UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 510
frame #15: 0x2d6ded28 QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 128
frame #16: 0x2d6da55c QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 360
frame #17: 0x2d6da3e4 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
frame #18: 0x2d6d9d80 QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 224
frame #19: 0x2d6d9b6e QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 434
frame #20: 0x2d6d3848 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 56
frame #21: 0x2a616fec CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
...
frame #28: 0x000fc840 MyApp`main(argc=1, argv=0x014a2a74) + 108 at main.m:14
```

[image: Label properties]

Comment: Can you post the code from your View Controller? Might show up something that could be causing this change.

Comment: @TomElliott The VC for the UIPageViewController or for the pages? The pages' VC just sets the label's text in viewDidLoad, based on what the UIPageViewController sets in viewControllerAtIndex.

Comment: Seeing UITrait stuff in your log. Do you use size classes in storyboard? I am not sure but I suppose that if you specify different fonts for different size classes, you get what you get.

Comment: I'd say the UIPageViewController and one offending page. Although Andy's thoughts seem like a better avenue to pursue.

Comment: @Andy Yes, the label has size classes set for the font. They differ only in size, all are GothamRounded-Book.

Comment: @TomElliott have re-arranged the code and now the individual page VC has no code, only IBOutlet properties. The only code now in the UIPageViewController is to instantiate a page VC and set the label's text.

Comment: To be honest it sounds like a bug. Try setting font for Any x Any to see if it makes any difference...

Comment: @Andy Cannot add a wAny hAny class. I assume that's already what the base is.

Comment: Even if I disable the autoshrink, it still changes the font face and size during layout.

Comment: @OrangeDog yeah I guess so. Defo a bug according to your call stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why?

Font autosizing does not work with custom fonts, this includes any use of size classes or the autoshrink settings. If size classes are not used, autshrink has no effect. If size classes are used, autoshrink is always active and will reset the font to the system font. I've tested Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7b3.

> How can I stop it?

Only use System fonts in the storyboard if any dynamic font sizing is used.
Override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to set the font you actually want. If the custom font has significantly different sizing properties than the system font, you will need to add a correction to the computed size.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    self.myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Custom" size:self.myLabel.font.pointSize];
}
```

Comment: My bug report was closed as a duplicate of 18519984.